# Move message between mailboxes using office 365 API

Tags: c#, office365

I would like to move email messages from one mailbox to another in Office 365 using some sort of API.
I looked up the API reference and the Move method  provides the ability to move to a folder only (reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#MessageoperationsMoveorcopymessages).
I know it was possible back then using Exchange's EWS service.
Do you know of a solution that might work in this case?
It is important to know, that simple forward won't do since I need to preserve the message's sender and receiver as is for search purposes.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Eyal, This isn't possible today with Office 365 REST APIs since a move can only be from one folder to another within a mailbox.  What is the scenario requiring cross-mailbox move?

Comment: We need to integrate with email archiving software that doesn't have an API. The software is called MailStore which can only archive emails from user mailboxes. We want to aggregate emails from multiple mailboxes into one place (similar to public folder). 
If we use email forwarding we will lose sender and receivers for search purposes. That's why we would like to simply move emails. I guess that creating a copy of the email in another mailbox is not possible as well.

Comment: Posted an answer based on the info in your comments.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a feature request for this to be done in the API https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35630110-please-provide-move-mail-functionality-across-ma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info provided, Exchange Web Services would be the only option for you.  The scope of a move and copy currently for our REST API is within a single mailbox.

Comment: Can I use exchange services with office 365?

Comment: Yes, you can use EWS with Office 365.